# LoginButton facebook android settext ();

Tags: android, facebook, button, user-interface, facebook-login

I have a problem while I try to set my text into `com.facebook.widget.LoginButton` 
nothing happened.
This is my layout:

```
            <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
                xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/btn_profile_facebook"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_edittext_without_bg_height"
                android:hint="@string/profile_facebook"
                facebook:confirm_logout="false"
                facebook:fetch_user_info="true"
                facebook:login_text=""
                facebook:logout_text=""
                style="@style/TextViewFacebook"
                />
```

this is my style

```
    <style name="TextViewFacebook" parent="@style/com_facebook_loginview_default_style">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/session_list_item_text_size_small</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>-->
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
</style>
```

So when I try to do `setText()` nothing happened (in text I am going to set user name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source of facebook sdk you can see that the text will be overwritten with a string from the ressources of facebook sdk:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/LoginButton.java  
Search for the Method `setButtonText()`.

Comment: So to set my own text I have to rewrite this class and create my method for setText because this one is private

Comment: Yes you will have to extenend this Class.